# Procedure pointers in RPGLE (PROCPTR)

Tags: ibm-midrange, rpgle

Can anyone provide any interesting usage examples of these?

Comment: This question is confusing. Can you please clarify what you are looking for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jjujuma,

For a trivial example you could use this to implement some Object Oriented style procedure like Draw.  You'd call a Circle_Draw procedure for a Circle or a Square_Draw procedure for a Square by assigning the appropriate %PADDR of the Circle_Draw or Square_Draw to your Draw procedure pointer.   When calling the Draw procedure pointer you hide which procedure (Circle_Draw or Square_Draw) you're calling.

Answer (score 4):

For a practical example, this can be used when implementing callbacks. A common callback can be found in the qsort() function in C. Yes, you can call that from ILERPG.

The `C` specification for qsort() is:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
void qsort(void *base, size_t num, size_t width,
           int(*compare)(const void *key, const void *element));
```

The `RPGLE` prototype would look like:

```
dcl-pr qsort      ExtName('qsort');
  array           Pointer value;
  num             Uns(10) value;
  width           Uns(10) value;
  compare         Pointer(*proc) value;
end-pr;
```

Here is a simple program that uses qsort():

```
   ctl-opt DftActGrp(*No) Actgrp(*New);

   dcl-pr qsort     ExtProc('qsort');
     array          Pointer value;
     num            Uns(10) value;
     width          Uns(10) value;
     compare        Pointer(*Proc) value;
   end-pr;

   dcl-s strings    Varchar(10) Dim(20);

   strings(1) = 'Does';
   strings(2) = 'this';
   strings(3) = 'array';
   strings(4) = 'sort';
   strings(5) = 'properly?';

   qsort(%addr(strings): 5: %size(strings): %paddr(compareStrings));

   dsply strings(1);
   dsply strings(2);
   dsply strings(3);
   dsply strings(4);
   dsply strings(5);

   return;

   dcl-proc compareStrings;
     dcl-pi *n Int(10);
       key      Like(strings);
       element  Like(strings);
     end-pi;

     dcl-s result    Int(10);

     if key < element;
       result = -1;
     elseif key = element;
       result = 0;
     else;
       result = 1;
     endif;

     return result;
   end-proc;
```

If you run it, the output will be:

```
DSPLY  array    
DSPLY  properly?
DSPLY  sort     
DSPLY  this     
DSPLY  Does
```

Answer (score 2):

I have used procedure pointers to encapsulate the logic for searching spooled files into its own service program named `SPLFFUNC` for make it easier to iterate over them.

In the calling program you can use code like:

```
ForEachSPLF(%paddr(ProcessSPLA0100) :                                 
         'SPLA0100'   :          // desired format, can be SPLF0100, SPLF0300, or SPLA0100                
         *BLANKS      :          // filter for all user names     
         ToUpper(SendQueue)    : // out queue                     
         ToUpper(SendQueueLib) : // out queue library             
         *BLANKS      :          // filter for all form types     
         *BLANKS      );         // filter for any user data
```

and

```
P ProcessSPLA0100...                                          
P                 B                                           
D                 PI                                          
D  SPLA                               LIKEDS(SPLA0100)     

P                 E
```

The pointed to procedure will get called one time for each spooled file matching the requested criteria.  This lets you return a lazy enumerable instead of an array.  I like this because it is reusable, it is not beholden to a specific size of array (since I never know how much to allocate), and it has a much smaller memory footprint since you only ever store one data structure at a time.  This is roughly equivalent to what you would do with a lambda in a language like C#.  Since the pointed to procedure can access any global variables in the client program, it closes over them to perform the real work of the client program.

The code in the service program handles all the gory detail of calling the APIs, reading the userspace object etc.  This detail can thus be kept out of the client program.

Note that RPG does not provide compile-type type checking for this kind of technique so you must make sure that the format you request and the data structure defined in the pointed to procedure match.

Service Program:

```
 H NOMAIN
 H DEBUG(*YES)
 H THREAD(*SERIALIZE)
 H BNDDIR('ERRFUNC')
 H OPTION(*SrcStmt:*NoDebugIO)
 H TEXT('Services for looping through spooled files')

 * To compile:
 *
 * CRTRPGMOD MODULE(QGPL/SPLFFUNC) SRCFILE(QGPL/QRPGLESRC)
 *
 * CRTSRVPGM SRVPGM(QGPL/SPLFFUNC) EXPORT(*SRCFILE)

 /copy QRPGLESRC,SPLFFUNCPR
 /copy QRPGLESRC,ERRFUNCPR

 ********************************************************************

 P ForEachSPLF     B                   EXPORT
 D                 PI
 D  ExecProcedure                  *   VALUE PROCPTR
 D  Format                       10A   VALUE
 D  UserName                     10A   VALUE
 D  OutQueue                     10A   VALUE
 D  OutQueueLib                  10A   VALUE
 D  FormType                     10A   VALUE
 D  UserData                     10A   VALUE


 D CrtUserSpace    PR                  EXTPGM('QUSCRTUS')
 D                               20A   CONST                                Name
 D                               10A   CONST                                Attribute
 D                               10I 0 CONST                                Intial size
 D                                1A   CONST                                Initial value
 D                               10A   CONST                                Authority
 D                               50A   CONST                                Text
 D                               10A   CONST OPTIONS(*nopass)               Replace existing
 D                            32767A   OPTIONS(*varsize:*nopass)            Error feedback


 D GetPointer      PR                  EXTPGM('QUSPTRUS')
 D                               20A   CONST                                User space name
 D                                 *                                        Pointer
 D                            32767A   OPTIONS(*varsize:*nopass)            Error feedback

 D DltUserSpace    PR                  EXTPGM('QUSDLTUS')
 D  QUSPTRUS                     20A   CONST                                User space name
 D                            32767A   OPTIONS(*varsize:*nopass)            Error feedback

 /copy qsysinc/qrpglesrc,qusec

 D ListSplFiles    PR                  EXTPGM('QUSLSPL')
 D                               20A   CONST                                userspace library
 D                                8A   CONST                                format
 D                               10A   CONST                                user name
 D                               20A   CONST                                output queue
 D                               10A   CONST                                form type
 D                               10A   CONST                                user data
 D                            32767A   OPTIONS(*varsize:*nopass)

 D GetSplfAttrib   PR                  EXTPGM('QUSRSPLA')
 D  receiver                           LIKEDS(SPLA0100)                     receiver structure
 D                               10I 0 CONST                                receiver length
 D                                8A   CONST                                format
 D                               26A   CONST                                qualified job name
 D                               16A   CONST                                internal job ID
 D                               16A   CONST                                internal SPLF ID
 D                               10A   CONST                                file name
 D                               10I 0 CONST                                file number
 D                            32767A   OPTIONS(*varsize:*nopass)

 *      Generic header format 0100
 D GenericHeader   DS                  BASED(UserSpacePointer) QUALIFIED
 D   ListOffset                  10I 0 OVERLAY(GenericHeader:125)
 D   ListCount                   10I 0 OVERLAY(GenericHeader:133)
 D   ListEachSize                10I 0 OVERLAY(GenericHeader:137)

 D SPLF1           DS                  LIKEDS(SPLF0100) BASED(FieldPointer)
 D SPLF3           DS                  LIKEDS(SPLF0300) BASED(FieldPointer)
 D SPLA1           DS                  LIKEDS(SPLA0100)
 D I               S              5I 0
 D SpaceName       S             20A
 D FileNum         S             10I 0 INZ(0)
 D reqFormat       S             10A

 D ptrSPLF0100     S               *   PROCPTR
 D procSPLF0100    PR                  EXTPROC(ptrSPLF0100)
 D  SPLF                               LIKEDS(SPLF0100)

 D ptrSPLF0300     S               *   PROCPTR
 D procSPLF0300    PR                  EXTPROC(ptrSPLF0300)
 D  SPLF                               LIKEDS(SPLF0300)

 D ptrSPLA0100     S               *   PROCPTR
 D procSPLA0100    PR                  EXTPROC(ptrSPLA0100)
 D  SPLF                               LIKEDS(SPLA0100)


 * Validate Parameters

 ptrSPLF0100 = ExecProcedure;
 ptrSPLF0300 = ExecProcedure;
 ptrSPLA0100 = ExecProcedure;
 IF Format <> 'SPLF0100' AND Format <> 'SPLF0300' AND
    Format <> 'SPLA0100';
   ThrowError('Spooled file information format must be -
   ''SPLF0100'', ''SPLF0300'', or ''SPLA0100''.');
 ENDIF;
 IF OutQueue = *BLANKS;
   OutQueue = '*ALL';
   OutQueueLib = *BLANKS;
 ELSE;
   IF OutQueueLib = *BLANKS;
     OutQueueLib = '*LIBL';
   ENDIF;
 ENDIF;
 IF UserName = *BLANKS;
   UserName = '*ALL';
 ENDIF;
 IF FormType = *BLANKS;
   FormType = '*ALL';
 ENDIF;
 IF UserData = *BLANKS;
   UserData = '*ALL';
 ENDIF;


 * To view this user space object:
 *
 * DSPF STMF('/QSYS.lib/QTEMP.lib/@SPOOLSPC.usrspc')
 *   or
 * DMPOBJ OBJ(QTEMP/@SPOOLSPC) OBJTYPE(*USRSPC)

 SpaceName = '@SPOOLSPC QTEMP';
 CrtUserSpace(SpaceName : '' : 131072 : x'00' :
             '*ALL':'List of spooled files':'*YES':QUSEC);

 *  DSPLY ('ListSplFiles' + SpaceName + Format + UserName);
 *  DSPLY (OutQueue + OutQueueLib + FormType + UserData);
 IF Format = 'SPLF0300';
   reqFormat = Format;
 ELSE;
   reqFormat = 'SPLF0100';
 ENDIF;
 ListSplFiles(SpaceName : reqFormat : UserName :
              OutQueue + OutQueueLib : FormType : UserData : QUSEC);

 GetPointer(SpaceName : UserSpacePointer) ;

 FOR I = 1 to GenericHeader.ListCount ;
   FieldPointer = UserSpacePointer
                + GenericHeader.ListOffset
                + (GenericHeader.ListEachSize * (I - 1)) ;

   IF Format = 'SPLF0100';
     procSPLF0100(SPLF1);
   ELSEIF Format = 'SPLF0300';
     procSPLF0300(SPLF3);
   ELSEIF Format = 'SPLA0100';
     GetSplfAttrib(SPLA1 : %size(SPLA1) : 'SPLA0100' : '*INT' :
                   SPLF1.InternalJobID : SPLF1.InternalSplID :
                   '*INT' :  FileNum : QUSEC);
     procSPLA0100(SPLA1);
   ENDIF; 
 ENDFOR;
 DltUserSpace(SpaceName : QUSEC) ;
 RETURN;

 P                 E
```

Service Program Prototypes:

```
 D ForEachSPLF     PR                  EXTPROC('ForEachSPLF')
 D  ExecProcedure                  *   VALUE PROCPTR
 D  Format                       10A   VALUE
 D  UserName                     10A   VALUE
 D  OutQueue                     10A   VALUE
 D  OutQueueLib                  10A   VALUE
 D  FormType                     10A   VALUE
 D  UserData                     10A   VALUE

 ********************************************************************

 D SPLF0100        DS                  TEMPLATE QUALIFIED INZ
 D  UserName                     10A   OVERLAY(SPLF0100:1)
 D  OutQName                     10A   OVERLAY(SPLF0100:11)
 D  OutQLibrary                  10A   OVERLAY(SPLF0100:21)
 D  FormType                     10A   OVERLAY(SPLF0100:31)
 D  UserSpecData                 10A   OVERLAY(SPLF0100:41)
 D  InternalJobID                16A   OVERLAY(SPLF0100:51)
 D  InternalSplID                16A   OVERLAY(SPLF0100:67)
 D  Reserved                      2A   OVERLAY(SPLF0100:83)
 D  AuxStorage                   10I 0 OVERLAY(SPLF0100:85)

 ********************************************************************

 D SPLF0300        DS                  TEMPLATE QUALIFIED INZ
 D  JobName                      10A   OVERLAY(SPLF0300:1)
 D  UserName                     10A   OVERLAY(SPLF0300:11)
 D  JobNumber                     6A   OVERLAY(SPLF0300:21)
 D  FileName                     10A   OVERLAY(SPLF0300:27)
 D  FileNumber                    9B 0 OVERLAY(SPLF0300:37)
 D  FileStatus                    9B 0 OVERLAY(SPLF0300:41)
 D  DateCreated                   7A   OVERLAY(SPLF0300:45)
 D  TimeCreated                   6A   OVERLAY(SPLF0300:52)
 D  Schedule                      1A   OVERLAY(SPLF0300:58)
 D  FileSysName                  10A   OVERLAY(SPLF0300:59)
 D  UserData                     10A   OVERLAY(SPLF0300:69)
 D  FormType                     10A   OVERLAY(SPLF0300:79)
 D  OutQName                     10A   OVERLAY(SPLF0300:89)
 D  OutQLibrary                  10A   OVERLAY(SPLF0300:99)
 D  AuxStorePool                  9B 0 OVERLAY(SPLF0300:109)
 D  Size                          9B 0 OVERLAY(SPLF0300:113)
 D  SizeMult                      9B 0 OVERLAY(SPLF0300:117)
 D  Pages                         9B 0 OVERLAY(SPLF0300:121)
 D  CopiesLeft                    9B 0 OVERLAY(SPLF0300:125)
 D  Priority                      1A   OVERLAY(SPLF0300:129)
 D  Reserved                      3A   OVERLAY(SPLF0300:130)
 D  InterPrintID                  9B 0 OVERLAY(SPLF0300:133)

 ********************************************************************

 D SPLA0100        DS                  TEMPLATE QUALIFIED INZ
 D  BytesReturned                10I 0 OVERLAY(SPLA0100:1)
 D  BytesAvail                   10I 0 OVERLAY(SPLA0100:5)
 D  InternalJobID                16A   OVERLAY(SPLA0100:9)
 D  InternalSplID                16A   OVERLAY(SPLA0100:25)
 D  JobName                      10A   OVERLAY(SPLA0100:41)
 D  UserName                     10A   OVERLAY(SPLA0100:51)
 D  JobNumber                     6A   OVERLAY(SPLA0100:61)
 D  FileName                     10A   OVERLAY(SPLA0100:67)
 D  FileNumber                   10I 0 OVERLAY(SPLA0100:77)
 D  FormType                     10A   OVERLAY(SPLA0100:81)
 D  UserData                     10A   OVERLAY(SPLA0100:91)
 D  Status                       10A   OVERLAY(SPLA0100:101)
 D  FileAvailable                10A   OVERLAY(SPLA0100:111)
 D  HoldBefore                   10A   OVERLAY(SPLA0100:121)
 D  SaveAfter                    10A   OVERLAY(SPLA0100:131)
 D  TotalPages                   10I 0 OVERLAY(SPLA0100:141)
 D  PageWritten                  10I 0 OVERLAY(SPLA0100:145)
 D  StartingPage                 10I 0 OVERLAY(SPLA0100:149)
 D  EndingPage                   10I 0 OVERLAY(SPLA0100:153)
 D  LastPagePrint                10I 0 OVERLAY(SPLA0100:157)
 D  Restart                      10I 0 OVERLAY(SPLA0100:161)
 D  TotalCopies                  10I 0 OVERLAY(SPLA0100:165)
 D  CopiesLeft                   10I 0 OVERLAY(SPLA0100:169)
 D  LinesPerInch                 10I 0 OVERLAY(SPLA0100:173)
 D  CharsPerInch                 10I 0 OVERLAY(SPLA0100:177)
 D  OutPriority                   2A   OVERLAY(SPLA0100:181)
 D  OutQueueName                 10A   OVERLAY(SPLA0100:183)
 D  OutQueueLib                  10A   OVERLAY(SPLA0100:193)
 D  DateCreated                   7A   OVERLAY(SPLA0100:203)
 D  TimeCreated                   6A   OVERLAY(SPLA0100:210)
 D  DeviceFileName...
 D                               10A   OVERLAY(SPLA0100:216)
 D  DeviceFileLib                10A   OVERLAY(SPLA0100:226)
 D  ProgramName                  10A   OVERLAY(SPLA0100:236)
 D  ProgramLib                   10A   OVERLAY(SPLA0100:246)
 D  AccountingCde                15A   OVERLAY(SPLA0100:256)
 D  PrintText                    30A   OVERLAY(SPLA0100:271)
 D  RecordLength                 10I 0 OVERLAY(SPLA0100:301)
 D  MaxRecords                   10I 0 OVERLAY(SPLA0100:305)
 D  DeviceType                   10A   OVERLAY(SPLA0100:309)
 D  PrinterType                  10A   OVERLAY(SPLA0100:319)
 D  DocumentName                 12A   OVERLAY(SPLA0100:329)
 D  FolderName                   64A   OVERLAY(SPLA0100:341)
 D  Sys36ProcName                 8A   OVERLAY(SPLA0100:405)
 D  PrintFidelity                10A   OVERLAY(SPLA0100:413)
 D  ReplaceUnprintable...
 D                                1A   OVERLAY(SPLA0100:423)
 D  ReplacementChar...
 D                                1A   OVERLAY(SPLA0100:424)
 D  PageLength                   10I 0 OVERLAY(SPLA0100:425)
 D  PageWidth                    10I 0 OVERLAY(SPLA0100:429)
 D  NumSeparators                10I 0 OVERLAY(SPLA0100:433)
 D  OverflowLine                 10I 0 OVERLAY(SPLA0100:437)
 D  MultiByteData                10A   OVERLAY(SPLA0100:441)
 D  DBCSExtenChar                10A   OVERLAY(SPLA0100:451)
 D  DBCSShiftOut                 10A   OVERLAY(SPLA0100:461)
 D  DBCSCharRot                  10A   OVERLAY(SPLA0100:471)
 D  DBCSCPI                      10I 0 OVERLAY(SPLA0100:481)
 D  GraphCharSet                 10A   OVERLAY(SPLA0100:485)
 D  CodePage                     10A   OVERLAY(SPLA0100:495)
 D  FormDefName                  10A   OVERLAY(SPLA0100:505)
 D  FormDefLib                   10A   OVERLAY(SPLA0100:515)
 D  SourceDrawer                 10I 0 OVERLAY(SPLA0100:525)
 D  PrinterFont                  10A   OVERLAY(SPLA0100:529)
 D  Sys36SPLFID                   6A   OVERLAY(SPLA0100:539)
 D  PageRotation                 10I 0 OVERLAY(SPLA0100:545)
 D  Justification                10I 0 OVERLAY(SPLA0100:549)
 D  PrintDuplex                  10A   OVERLAY(SPLA0100:553)
 D  FoldRecords                  10A   OVERLAY(SPLA0100:563)
 D  ControlChar                  10A   OVERLAY(SPLA0100:573)
 D  AlignForms                   10A   OVERLAY(SPLA0100:583)
 D  PrintQuality                 10A   OVERLAY(SPLA0100:593)
 D  FormFeed                     10A   OVERLAY(SPLA0100:603)
 D  VolumesArray                 71A   OVERLAY(SPLA0100:613)
 D  FileLabelID                  17A   OVERLAY(SPLA0100:684)
 D  ExchangeType                 10A   OVERLAY(SPLA0100:701)
 D  CharacterCode                10A   OVERLAY(SPLA0100:711)
 D  TotalRecords                 10I 0 OVERLAY(SPLA0100:721)
 D  PagesPerSide                 10I 0 OVERLAY(SPLA0100:725)
 D  FrontOvlName                 10A   OVERLAY(SPLA0100:729)
 D  FrontOvlLib                  10A   OVERLAY(SPLA0100:739)
 D  FrontOvlOffsetDown...
 D                               15P 5 OVERLAY(SPLA0100:749)
 D  FrontOvlOffsetAcross...
 D                               15P 5 OVERLAY(SPLA0100:757)
 D  BackOvlName                  10A   OVERLAY(SPLA0100:765)
 D  BackOvlLib                   10A   OVERLAY(SPLA0100:775)
 D  BackOvlOffsetDown...
 D                               15P 5 OVERLAY(SPLA0100:785)
 D  BackOvlOffsetAcross...
 D                               15P 5 OVERLAY(SPLA0100:793)
 D  UnitOfMeasure                10A   OVERLAY(SPLA0100:801)
 D  PageDefName                  10A   OVERLAY(SPLA0100:811)
 D  PageDefLib                   10A   OVERLAY(SPLA0100:821)
 D  LineSpacing                  10A   OVERLAY(SPLA0100:831)
 D  PointSize                    15P 5 OVERLAY(SPLA0100:841)
 D  FrontMarginOffsetDown...
 D                               15P 5 OVERLAY(SPLA0100:849)
 D  FrontMarginOffsetAcross...
 D                               15P 5 OVERLAY(SPLA0100:857)
 D  BackMarginOffsetDown...
 D                               15P 5 OVERLAY(SPLA0100:865)
 D  BackMarginOffsetAcross...
 D                               15P 5 OVERLAY(SPLA0100:873)
 D  LengthOfPage                 15P 5 OVERLAY(SPLA0100:881)
 D  WidthOfPage                  15P 5 OVERLAY(SPLA0100:889)
 D  MeasurementMethod...
 D                               10A   OVERLAY(SPLA0100:897)
 D  AFPResource                   1A   OVERLAY(SPLA0100:907)
 D  CharSetName                  10A   OVERLAY(SPLA0100:908)
 D  CharSetLib                   10A   OVERLAY(SPLA0100:918)
 D  CodePageName                 10A   OVERLAY(SPLA0100:928)
 D  CodePageLib                  10A   OVERLAY(SPLA0100:938)
 D  CodedFontName                10A   OVERLAY(SPLA0100:948)
 D  CodedFontLib                 10A   OVERLAY(SPLA0100:958)
 D  DBCSFontName                 10A   OVERLAY(SPLA0100:968)
 D  DBCSFontLib                  10A   OVERLAY(SPLA0100:978)
 D  UserDefFile                  10A   OVERLAY(SPLA0100:988)
 D  ReduceOutput                 10A   OVERLAY(SPLA0100:998)
 D  ConstBackOvl                  1A   OVERLAY(SPLA0100:1008)
 D  OutputBin                    10I 0 OVERLAY(SPLA0100:1009)
 D  CCSID                        10I 0 OVERLAY(SPLA0100:1013)
 D  UserDefText                 100A   OVERLAY(SPLA0100:1017)
 D  CreatedSystem                 8A   OVERLAY(SPLA0100:1117)
 D  CreatedID                     8A   OVERLAY(SPLA0100:1125)
 D  CreatedUser                  10A   OVERLAY(SPLA0100:1133)
 D                                2A   OVERLAY(SPLA0100:1143)
 D  OffsetUserDef                10I 0 OVERLAY(SPLA0100:1145)
 D  NumberUserDef                10I 0 OVERLAY(SPLA0100:1149)
 D  LengthUserDef                10I 0 OVERLAY(SPLA0100:1153)
 D  UsrDefData                  255A   OVERLAY(SPLA0100:1157)
 D  UsrDefObjName                10A   OVERLAY(SPLA0100:1412)
 D  UsrDefObjLib                 10A   OVERLAY(SPLA0100:1422)
 D  UsrObjType                   10A   OVERLAY(SPLA0100:1432)
 D                                3A   OVERLAY(SPLA0100:1442)
 D  CharSetPtSz                  15P 5 OVERLAY(SPLA0100:1445)
 D  CodedFontPtSz                15P 5 OVERLAY(SPLA0100:1453)
 D  DBCSFontPtSz                 15P 5 OVERLAY(SPLA0100:1461)
 D  AuxStorPool                  10I 0 OVERLAY(SPLA0100:1469)
 D  SPLFSize                     10I 0 OVERLAY(SPLA0100:1473)
 D  SPLFSizeMult                 10I 0 OVERLAY(SPLA0100:1477)
 D  IPJobID                      10I 0 OVERLAY(SPLA0100:1481)
 D  SPLFSecurity                  1A   OVERLAY(SPLA0100:1485)
 D  SPLFAuthent                   1A   OVERLAY(SPLA0100:1486)
 D  WriterDateBeg                 7A   OVERLAY(SPLA0100:1487)
 D  WriterTimeBeg                 6A   OVERLAY(SPLA0100:1494)
 D  WriterDateEnd                 7A   OVERLAY(SPLA0100:1500)
 D  WriterTimeEnd                 6A   OVERLAY(SPLA0100:1507)
 D  JobSysName                    8A   OVERLAY(SPLA0100:1513)
 D  AuxStorPoolDv                10A   OVERLAY(SPLA0100:1521)
 D  ExpireDate                    7A   OVERLAY(SPLA0100:1531)
```

Answer (score 0):

For example, CEEHDLR/CEEHDLU (un)registers a user-written condition handler for the current stack (entry) frame.